# Save downloads in the same location I saved the previous download in Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Firefox does this automatically, but Chrome keeps reverting to the default "downloads" location.

If I am saving 100 photos, I don't want to have to keep navigating the same path to photos every single time I save a photo file. I want the default location in the "save as" dialog box to be the last location saved.

Comment: It may be easier to simply download all the files to the downloads folder, and move them later. Windows explorer has many useful filtering features, which should make finding the new files in the download folder trivial.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open up chrome settings.
2. Search for downloads.
3. Put your download location and uncheck the box for asking each time for download location.

Alternatively, you can add your locations to "Favorites" which always appear in left pane on save as dialog box.

Are you using latest version of chrome?

Comment: Yes, when using the ask every time feature it should remember the last location. If it is not, then there is something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this issue by turning off a Chrome extension that was overriding my download settings. It was a media / photo downloader.
Once I disabled it, my new saves referenced the last file location as it should.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).